# Windows Registry cleanup control

Tags: windows-registry

Windows has an automatic event in which some registry entries are purged. I see this event in the Event Viewer with the ID=16. It seems that the cleanup is frequently triggered by Windows Update.
In my Java application I store data in [Computer\HKEY_USERS<SID>\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs] and this gets frequently deleted. (I am protecting the data using DPAPI - thus not using the HKLM)

1. Is there a way for me to trigger this clean up job so I could study exactly what is going on?
2. Is there a way to prevent the automatic cleanup from touching a specific registry key?

Comment: What operating system?  The last time I saw this (and so occasionally no need to do anything) was Windows 7.  Never on Windows 10.

Comment: This is happening to me on Windows Server 2016 and 2019

Comment: I do not know for sure in this case. See if this article sheds any light:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-windows-registry-checker-tool-scanreg-exe-aaae4323-daa2-8477-5a4e-2a273779fdf0

Comment: Are the user accounts your program is running on regular user accounts (local or domain)?

Comment: John, the article instructs to use scanreg which is no longer part of Windows.
Robert, I am using local accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal for Windows to do registry cleanup from time to time.
The event, as you found, is
[Event ID: 16](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-16-source-Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General-eventno-11563-phase-1.htm).

This can be a very aggressive registry cleanup, and even more so after
a major Windows update, up to requiring for some applications to be
re-installed.

If your app suffers also from this problem, try to change the location
in the registry in which your data is stored, or move it into a file,
to protect it from Windows.
As far as I know, there is no other solution to protect your data.

Comment: Thank you Harry. I also saw your answer in thread #1647864. Before moving, I am trying to reproduce the issue though - so far with no success.

Comment: The cleanup after a major Windows update is more aggressive than the regular one, or in my case I would have been obliged to reinstall my problematic apps every month.

Comment: I'm ending up moving the registry keys to HKLM and assigning custom access permissions to them.